# Unetbootin does not show Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: unetbootin

Unetbootin does not show Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I do not see a way to force an update of the list.  Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if it updates automatically or how that works. I just installed Unetbootin on a fresh 13.10 install today and it gives me 6 different variations of 12.04 to choose from. So maybe uninstalling and reinstalling Unetbootin would help, I'm not sure.

Alternatively, you could just go to: 

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop 

Select 32 bit or 64 bit and download the ISO file onto your computer. Then open up Unetbootin, choose Disk Image instead of Distribution, find the file you just downloaded and install it.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it updates automatically or how that works. I just installed Unetbootin on a fresh 13.10 install today and it gives me 6 different variations of 12.04 to choose from. So maybe

Alternatively, you could just go to:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Select 32 bit or 64 bit and download the ISO file onto your computer. Then open up Unetbootin, choose Disk Image instead of Distribution, find the file you just downloaded and install it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, I tried the download site, got the iso and made an image on a USB, no luck.  The boot process just hangs and the screen goes black.  I doubt there are logs at that time but it would be helpful.  Thank you for your time and input, it is appreciated.